# Is $f\mapsto f'((a+b)/2$ a continuous linear functional on $C^1([a,b])$?

Tags: functional-analysis

I've been stuck on this problem for a while: let $C^1([a,b])$ be the space of real-valued continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$. Does there exist an $M\in\mathbf{R}$ such that for $T:f\mapsto f'((a+b)/2)$ and every $f\in C^1([a,b])$, $|T(f)|\leq M\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x)|$? My guess is no, but I have trouble proving it. My first attempt was to take $\{x^n\}$ on $[0,1]$, but unfortunately $f'(1/2)=n2^{-n+1}\to 0$.

Comment: what was your second attempt?

Comment: Is your $C^1([a, b])$ equipped with the supremum norm? This seems tacitly assumed in your question, but I just want to make sure. And if this is the case, you may try $$ f_n(x) = \tfrac{1}{n} \arctan(n^2(x - \tfrac{1}{2})). $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, can't believe I didn't think of using trigonometric functions. If we let $f_n(x)=\sin((2n)^2x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$, $f_n'(x)=(2n)^2\cos(n^2x)$ and so $f_n'(\pi)=4n^2$, while $\sup_{x\in[0,2\pi]}|f_n|=1$.